# I want to download a script from cdn and use it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cdn

I wanted to download a script and use it instead of using cdn

The cdn links are

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-object-assign@1.1.0/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding.min.js"></script>
```

Instead I downloaded and tried to use

```
<script src="./js/encoding.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/object-assign-auto.js"></script>
```

But it doesnt work it shows

> NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested
>   URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).

I think I am not using the downloaded files in the right way. suggestions please, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add thr scripts to the `angular.json` file, in the `scripts` sections.

Paths starts at the root of your folder, so it should be `js/encoding.js` :

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
        "assets": [...],
        "styles": [...],
        "scripts": [
          "js/encoding.js"
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have the scripts in the right place or the relative path "./js" is not the correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `angular` in your post, you must not include scripts inside the template html. You could include them in the index.html to load them directly from cdn or download and include them inside the `scripts` array of `angular-cli.json`

If you are not using angular, the problem could be an `incorrect filename`, `incorrect folder` or even wrong `relative` path.

Comment: I am using angular and I was including it in index.html but moving it to angular.json worked for me

Comment: Yeah, this is because the js/ folder is not copied to the dist/ folder generated from build.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can refer a cdn or static url in the index.html, but if you download you can include in the angular.json. Glad it worked!

Comment: @RamakanthReddy do feel free to accept an answer that helped so that people can refer it in future

Comment: I downvoted for parroting an existing answer (minus the either incorrect or irrelevant information). Next time, think about upvoting another answer you agree with, instead of posting a duplicate of it ! (no hard feelings)

Comment: Lol. None taken. But as you can read from the question there was no indication that the angular framework was indeed being used. The only indicator was a tag which could have very well been misplaced. I just gave information and you clearly can see I wrote the answer myself instead of the parrot copy x paste.