# Angular 7 how to include inline JS script into component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, algolia

I'd like to install places.js library into my Angular 7 project, but I have a problem. I've included following script into my 'index.html' file

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.16.4"></script>
  <script>
    var placesAutocomplete = places({
      appId: 'myAppId',
      apiKey: 'myApiKey',
      container: document.querySelector('#addressInput')
    });
  </script>
```

but it is working only when I have

```
<input type="search" id="address-input" placeholder="Where are we going?" />
```

in my 'index.html'. I've tried to include this input into my component but it's not working and I have an error

```
places.js@1.16.4:1 Uncaught Error: Algolia Places: 'container' must point to an <input> element.
```

Is it possible to attach this script and make it working? In the documentation there is nothing about typescript. I've also tried to npm install and

```
import * from 'places.js'
```

but have same issue. Could someone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to download a script from cdn and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551487/i-want-to-download-a-script-from-cdn-and-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use it embedded in an Angular Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import places from "places.js";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "my-app";

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const placesAutocomplete = places({
      appId: "appId",
      apiKey: "appKey",
      container: document.querySelector("#address-input")
    });
  }
}
```

you should place also this in your `polyfill.js`in order to make it work:

```
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined }
};

(window as any).global = window;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your way but not success.

You need download `places.js` file and put to a script folder.

Update `angular.json` file at builder > scripts

```
 "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
        "assets": [...],
        "styles": [...],
        "scripts": [
          "script/places.js"
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep all your Place code in a component and initialize it on `ngOnItit()`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Places from 'places';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './yourComponent.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  ngOnInit(){
    Places({
      appId: 'myAppId',
      apiKey: 'myApiKey',
      container: document.querySelector('#addressInput')
    });
  }
}
```

yourComponent.html:

```
<input type="search" id="address-input" placeholder="Where are we going?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my observation this needs the input loaded before ever being called and you are attaching it to your index before the input ever loads. 
Of course this won't work

```
var placesAutocomplete = places({
  appId: 'myAppId',
  apiKey: 'myApiKey',
  container: document.querySelector('#addressInput')
});
```

There are few other ways you can do this but in my case, i would create a service, something like

```
declare var places:any;
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class PlacesServices {
      setup(){
        var placesAutocomplete = places({
        appId: 'myAppId',
        apiKey: 'myApiKey',
        container: document.querySelector('#addressInput')
       });
      }

}
```

then inject it to your component and only call it when the input with the correct id is loaded, you need ngAfterViewInit to make sure the views are loaded

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.placesService.setup();
  //i would be calling the setup here on the component with the input
}
```

The js script can either be added on the index.html or just like Hien answer pointed.

I just typed it, might have some typo but you should get the idea. Hope it works for you!