# Angular 7: External scipts in component

Tags: angular, embed

I'd like to embed this code into my angular 7 application.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/1716276/embeddable_assessments/disc/disc_assessment_v1.1.0.css" /> 
<script src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/1716276/embeddable_assessments/disc/disc_assessment_v1.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="disc_assessment_root" data-api-token="token-here"></div>
<script>
    window.crystalKnowsDISCResponse = function (response) {
        console.log('Here is the personality JSON response:', response)
    }
</script>
```

So the link and the script should stay in index.html, but i must use `<div id="disc_assessment_root" data-api-token="token-here"></div>` in my custom component, and

```
window.crystalKnowsDISCResponse = function (response) {
   console.log('Here is the personality JSON response:', response)
}
```

to get the results that the API returns.

Comment: so what had you tried so far?

Comment: I downloaded the script and saved it as a local js file, imported it in angular.json and tried to declare a variable in the ts file of the component, but nothing happened.
And tried something like this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098810/angular-7-how-to-include-inline-js-script-into-component

Comment: If someone else has this same problem, just follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular